# VBA - Combine several cells into a single string in Excel

Tags: string, excel, range, vba

I'm working on a spreadsheet full of warranty data and there are three adjacent columns where different members of the service team can enter comments and trouble codes they find. I'm writing a macro to parse the comments looking for the trouble codes and I can get it to search one column fine, but I can't seem to get it to search adjacent columns in one step.

My goal is to combine the three adjacent cells into a single string. I don't care about space or comma delimiters, the regex will still work, I just want the text of several adjacent cells combined into a single string which I will then pass to the regex. Here's what I have so far:

```
    'set regex input; if searching more than one column, combine into single string
    If ColNum > 0 Then
        For m = 0 To ColNum - 1
            strInput = strInput & Cells(i, ReadCol + m).Value
        Next
    Else
        strInput = Cells(i, ReadCol).Value
    End If
```

Where ReadCol is the starting column to search, ColNum is the number of adjacent columns to search (ColNum = 0 will only search the first column), i is the row iterator (each row is one warranty record), and strInput is what gets passed to regex. If I'm only searching one column, the macro works perfectly. If I try to search more than one, it throws a type mismatch error. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is `.Vale`?  should it be `.Value`?

Comment: Ah, good catch. Fixed it, but I'm still getting the mismatch error.

Comment: When you say Error Codes are you saying codes you use internally that are text values in Excel, or are they actual errors in excel?

Comment: Sorry, the error codes are internal to our company. Service people will enter the codes they find in the comments box and they're formatted in a specific way (P followed by 4 numbers), so the macro is supposed to step through all the comments and pick out the P-codes.

Comment: What is the value of `ReadCol` and how is it declared?

Comment: ReadCol is a user input value. When the macro starts, it pops up a box and asks the user input the starting column ("AF" for example). The message box takes in the input as the ReadCol variable.

Comment: There is your problem, You need to convert the `AF` to a number, you cannot add a number to a letter.  So add a long variable and assign it the value: `NewVar = Columns(ReadCol).Column` then use that new variable in the second criterion of the Cells(): `strInput = strInput & Cells(i, NewVar + m).Value`

Comment: Or you can skip the whole new variable and just use: `strInput = strInput & Cells(i, Columns(ReadCol).Column + m).Value`

Comment: Ahhh, that was it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Just a quick note, next time please include the declarations of all variables and how they are assigned a value that impact the line on which the error is thrown.  It would have made this quicker to resolve.

Comment: Understood. Thanks again!

Also, do I need to mark the thread as solved or anything?

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do the trick. You may need to modify the sheet number and starting cell but otherwise you'll be good to go. O ya, you'll also need to modify the number of rows of data you want to go through.

```
Sub Combine_Cells_Into_string()
'The Combined string
Dim Comments_and_Codes As String

'Three Adjacent cells' data
Dim comment1 As String
Dim comment2 As String
Dim code1 As String

Dim Rows_of_data_cnt As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Rows_of_data_cnt = 10
'Iterating through your sheet
For i = 0 To Rows_of_data_cnt - 1   '-1 since we are starting at index 0 and not 1
    comment1 = Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Text  'Your sheet number and starting cell may be different
    comment2 = Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(i, 1).Text
    code1 = Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(i, 2).Text
    Comments_and_Codes = comment1 + comment2 + code1  'Combining your data
    'Do Something with your string(This is up to you buddy)
    Sheet1.Range("G5").Offset(i, 0).Value = Comments_and_Codes
Next

End Sub
```